# Bootstrap Navbar fixed on top, Container centered vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My page is very simple : it is made of a navbar, and two panels.

I am trying to get my navbar fixed on top, and the two panels vertically centered (for any screen size or browsers).

These two panels are placed in a container.

I have been unsuccessful in vertically centering the container so far.

Here is what I have now :

[image]

Here is what I want to achieve :

[image]

Here is my code :

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.panel-default1 {
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-default2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: -15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <nav class="navbar transparent navbar-static-top">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <p>Welcome</p>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div class="container d-flex h-100">

    <div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">

      <!-- 1st panel -->
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-4" id="panel">

        <div class="panel panel-default1">

          <div class="panel-body">

            <p>Blablabla</p>

          </div>
          <!-- panel body -->
        </div>
        <!-- panel-default1-->
      </div>
      <!-- col md 4 -->

      <!-- 2nd panel -->

      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-8" id="panel2">

        <div class="panel panel-default2">

          <div class="panel-body">

            <p>Blablabla</p>

          </div>
          <!-- panel-body -->

        </div>
        <!-- panel-default2-->

      </div>
      <!-- col md 8 -->

    </div>
    <!-- row -->

  </div>
  <!-- container-->

</body>
```

As you can see from the HTML, I have tried to use Bootstrap's flexbox on container and row, without success.

Please advise a working solution to vertically center my container, except the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

From what I notice, you want an element to be centered, but not using all 12 columns, so you can use `mx-auto` to center an element that has less than 12 columns. You also said

```css
.noMX {
  background-color: red;
}
.withMX {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="noMX col-8">awts</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="withMX col-8 mx-auto">awts</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To center it vertically you can try this. First add `height: 100%` to the body and `html`, since I noticed you used `h-100` meaning you want 100% height on the container. You also need to wrap the panels into another `div` so that the element that will be centered is the div wrapper rather than the panels. I also removed `md` in the columns so that you can the result in smaller viewport

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: Red;
}

#panel {
  background-color: blue;
}

#panel2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar transparent navbar-static-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <p>Welcome</p>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="wrapper container h-100">
  <div class="row d-flex align-items-center h-100">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 mb-4" id="panel">
          <div class="panel panel-default1">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Blablabla</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8" id="panel2">
          <div class="panel panel-default2">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Blablabla</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to center the container vertically. The two panels are on the same row, and occupy 12 columns together (4 + 8).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `col-4` and `col-8` for columns inside `row` inside container
see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width)

see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/wtt16L1u/)

Edit:
to align them vertically you should be able to just add [align-items-center](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment) class on a row, without additional css.
Updated example

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.panel-default1 {
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background:red;
}

.panel-default2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: -15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background:green;
}
.navbar-header{
    float: none;
    padding: 20px;
    background:black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>

  <nav class="navbar transparent navbar-static-top text-center">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <p>Welcome</p>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <!-- 1st panel -->
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-4" id="panel">

        <div class="panel panel-default1">

          <div class="panel-body">

            <p>Blablabla</p>

          </div>
          <!-- panel body -->
        </div>
        <!-- panel-default1-->
      </div>
      <!-- col md 4 -->

      <!-- 2nd panel -->

      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-8" id="panel2">

        <div class="panel panel-default2">

          <div class="panel-body">

            <p>Blablabla</p>

          </div>
          <!-- panel-body -->

        </div>
        <!-- panel-default2-->

      </div>
      <!-- col md 8 -->

    </div>
    <!-- row -->

  </div>
  <!-- container-->

</body>
```